# How to add more than one circles to this same progress bar using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I am trying to create a progress bar with multiple money til current date  based on this [UX sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mDsl.png)

So far, I am able to display the first circle. Here's an output [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPsXm.png) of my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class={`col-md-12`}>
  <h3 class="line-bottom mt-0">Money Earned to Date</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 12%; background: #ed687c;">
          <span class="progress-icon fa fa-dollar-sign" style="color: #707070; border-color: #707070;"></span>
          <div class="progress-value">$100</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progressbar-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #848484;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.progress {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: visible;
    background: #f4bc25;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
}
.progress .progress-bar {
    position: relative;
}
.progress .progress-icon {
    width: 55px;
    height: 53px;
    line-height: 47px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 19px;
    background: #fff;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #707070;
}
.progress-value {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    right: 11px;
}
```

Can someone please help me finish the remaining parts on the UX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make more circles dynamically you have to make it with Javacript but if you want it static (with only 5 circles) then here you go :

```css
.row,.progress{ position: relative;width: 100%;}
    .progress-bar{position:relative;background: #f6ba2b;height: 24px; border-radius:36px}
    .progress-bar > .offCircle{
      position:absolute;width:100%;
      height:100%;
      /* background:red; */
    }
    
    .progress:after,
    .progress-bar:before,
    .progress-bar:after,
    .progress-bar > .offCircle:before, 
    .progress-bar > .offCircle:after
    {
     position:absolute;
     color: #707070;
     top: 0;
     width:33px;
     height: 33px;
     background:#fff;
     margin-top: -7.5px;
     margin-top: -6.5px;
     border-radius:36px;
     border: 2px solid #707070;
     text-shadow: 0 0 0px black;
     line-height: 2.2;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .progress-bar > .offCircle:before{
     content: '$\A 100';
     left:1.67%;
    }
    
    .progress-bar > .offCircle:after{
    
     content: '$\A 500';
     left:8.33%;
    }
    .progress-bar:before{
     content: '$$\A 1000';
     left:16.67%;
    }
    .progress-bar:after{
     content: '$$\A 2500';
     left:41.76%;
    }
    .progress:after{
     content: '$$\A 5000';
     left:83.33%;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar">
                <span class="offCircle"></span>
                <div class="progress-value fa fa-dollar-sign"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

to make it animate add css transition for the effect, you have to calculate specific value as % and pass it to a Progress-bar with javascript, you can do it in many ways.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to complete the rest of the parts on my own.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6KZa.png)

In case if anyone is interested, here's the complete code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h3 class="heading">Money Earned to Date</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="checkout-wrap">
        <ul class="checkout-bar">
          <li class="visited first">
            <a href="#">$100</a>
          </li>
          <li class="previous first">$500</li>
          <li class="active">
            $1,000
            <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 85%; background: #cc504c;"></div>
            <div class="progress-value">$1,500</div>
          </li>
          <li class="next">$2,500</li>
          <li>$5,000</li>
        </ul>
        <h2 class="currentMoney">$1,500.00</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
  from {
    left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    left: 50%;
  }
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "PT Sans Caption", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: #777;
}

.checkout-wrap {
  color: #444;
  font-family: "PT Sans Caption", sans-serif;
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.checkout-bar {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
ul.checkout-bar li {
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 14px 20px 14px 80px;
  position: relative;
}
ul.checkout-bar li:before {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 20px;
  line-height: 37px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  z-index: 2;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.active {
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.active:before {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
  border-color: #707070;
  color: #707070;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.visited {
  background: #ECECEC;
  color: #444;
  z-index: 3;
  padding-left: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.visited:before {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
  border-color: #707070;
  color: #707070;
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "$";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "$";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "$$";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(4):before {
  content: "$$";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(5):before {
  content: "$$";
}
ul.checkout-bar a {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.active .progress-value{
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f4bc25;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -113px;
  right: -23px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.active .t_progress-bar:after{
  content: "\F3C5";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: -88px;
  right: -10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #f4bc25;
}
.finances .checkout-wrap .currentMoney {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #f4bc25;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .checkout-bar li.active:after {
    -webkit-animation: myanimation 3s 0;
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    background-color: #f4bc25;
    content: "";
    height: 28px;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .checkout-wrap {
    margin: 80px auto 0 auto
  }
  ul.checkout-bar {
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar:before {
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    background-color: #f4bc25;
    border-radius: 15px;
    content: " ";
    height: 28px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 17%;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar li:before {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    left: 40%;
    line-height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -65px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar li.visited {
    background: none;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar li.visited:after {
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    background-color: #f4bc25;
    content: "";
    height: 28px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```